# How to set custom title letters spacing for UINavigationBar in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar, nsmutableattributedstring

Just as described above, I wonder if there is some way to set custom letter spacing for UINavigationBar's title.

I know there is a way to set letter spacing to for ex. label by using NSMutableAttributedString, but unfortunately UINavigation bar does not work that way.

Is there any workaround for setting that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSAttributrString for UINavigationBar title:

```
NSDictionary *attributrs = @{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeFont : [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14.0]};
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: attributrs];
```

You can add it to AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: methods and all of your NSNavBar will apply this.

Answer (score 0):

is possible, set `self.navigationItem.titleView` with any view you need, possible `UILlabel`